# API call to shell32.dll via FindExecutableA returns "Can not find the specific path" on UNC paths

Tags: smalltalk, windows-xp-sp3, shell32.dll

I am doing an API call to `FindExecutableA` (Ansi version of FindExecutable) via `shell32.dll` from Smalltalk, but when I send UNC paths like

```
\\\serverName\\sharedFolder\filename
```

it returns error code 2, which basically means that the system could not find the given path.

The strange thing is that when I use paths like

```
\\\myPcName\C$\sharedFolder\filename
```

where `C$` is the shared name of `C:\` in my Pc, then it works.

I would like to make it work for "normal" UNC paths like the first one I wrote above. The system I am using is Windows XP SP3 and the `shell32.dll` has version number 6.0.2900.6072

I've been searching the net without luck. Has anyone got any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Smalltalk are you using? Squeak/Pharo? Cincom? Dolphin? Other?

Comment: Are you sure with the number of backslashes in your examples? The paths should be `\\serverName\sharedFolder\filename` and `\\myPcName\C$\sharedFolder\filename`, right?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx
the error code `2`returned from `FindExecutable` is: "The specified file was not found"

This means your UNC paths are invalid, use `\\servername\sharename\dirname\filename`